# Recuperar diretório onde o apk foi criado pelo gulp com o plugin cordova-lib

Tags: android, ionic, gulp

Boa noite,

Estou com um problema para recuperar o diretório onde o arquivo apk foi gerado. Utilizo o plugin cordova-lib no gulp para fazer build de uma aplicação ionic.

O "real" problema é que não consigo recuperar o local default, nem mesmo informar um local para geração desse apk. Se o caminho fosse fixo, conseguiria mover o arquivo para um local desejado, mas fiz o teste em diversos computadores e o diretório de geração difere entre eles.

Segue um exemplo do gulpfile:

```
var gulp    = require("gulp"),
    cordova = require("cordova-lib").cordova;

gulp.task("build", function (callback) {
    cordova.build({
        "platforms": ["android"],
        "options": {
            argv: []
        }
    }, callback);
});
```

Agradeço caso alguém saiba uma forma de recuperar/setar esse diretório de output ou até mesmo conheça algum outro plugin para build de uma aplicação ionic.